# How can i leave loop when element was found?

Tags: loops, if-statement, protractor

I am working on a method that shall select a valid entry (depends on status).
If a valid entry is found, it should leave the loop  and go to another function.

But my code does not work. What do i have to change?

```
function DetectVehicle(vehicles) {
        browser.waitForAngular();
        if (vehicles > 1) {
            basics.checkElementPresent(PDP.elementSelectCar);
            for (var car = 0; car < vehicles; car++) {
                (function (params) {
                    try {
                        PDP.elementSelectCar.click();
                        PDP.elementCarList.get(car).click();
                        PDP.elementStatus.getAttribute("class").then(function (value) {
                            value = value.split("-").pop();
                            console.log(value);
                            if (value == "available" || value == "acquired") GoOn();
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log("Error detecting status: " + err);
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log("Error detecting status: " + err);
                    }
                })(car);
                console.log(car);
            }
        }
        else if (vehicles == 1) {
            //this user has only one vehicle, so nothing has to be done :)
        }
    };
```

I know that the "GoOn" function will now rise more than one time, because each list has more than one valid entry. But how can i fix this?
NOTE: break; does not work. It says "illegal break statement"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
break;
```

After the GoOn() function

Comment: No one has an Idea? I am still stuck at this one1